# input keystrokes to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I'm trying to add some automation to Autotask by using tampermonkey in Chrome.
I have been able to Automatically select Drop down selections easy enough by selecting the index.

There are a couple of fields which have some auto completion which will not allow me to just insert a value. Si someone able to point me in the right direction so that I can input values into these fields.

Thank you kindly.

```
<span id="txtAllocationCode" imageid="txtAllocationCode_image" 
controlid="txtAllocationCode_ATTextEdit" anchorid="txtAllocationCode_anchor"
                          style="display:inline-block;">
<input name="txtAllocationCode:ATTextEdit" type="text" 
     id="txtAllocationCode_ATTextEdit" class="txtBlack8Class" 
      autocomplete="off" data_field_uniqueid="txtAllocationCode_values" 
     onkeyup="AutoCompleteTextKeyUp(document.getElementById(
    'txtAllocationCode_ATTextEdit'),event)" 
    dataselectortype="AllocationCodes" onmouseover="this.title=this.value;"
     dataselectortextbox="true" 
      onblur="AutoCompleteTextOnBlur(document.getElementById(
         'txtAllocationCode_ATTextEdit'))" data_field="txtAllocationCode_values"
             onfocus="AutoCompleteTextOnFocus(document.getElementById(
                   'txtAllocationCode_ATTextEdit'))"  
      autocompletehashvalues="AutoCompleteHashValues='&amp;selectorwarn=0'" 
     novaluedisplaytext="" dataselectorsubtype="AllocationCode_LaborAndTime" 
      style="width: 198px;" title="">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should put values into input fields.

```
$(function() {
    $("#txtAllocationCode_ATTextEdit").val("your value here");
});
```

Comment: Hello, It will input the value but the form validation that that field is having performed on it doesn't see the value change so it doesn't work. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

How do you set the value for the input? Are you using the jquery as the library to manipulate the html element?

Maybe you can try to unbind the event of onkeyup, onmouseover and onfocus before you set the value to the input element.

Comment: yeah jquery is what I am using.